# How to calculate the time of turning on/off LEDs in four 8-bit shift registers with ATtiny2313-20U

Tags: microcontroller

I am planing to build a project with 4 8-bit shift registers (74HC595) connected in series (daisy chain) and the MCU is ATtiny2313-20U.

I know the max frequency for the MCU is 20MHz. Based on that, how do I figure out how fast I can blink the LEDs, given that I have to input 32 (4x8) bits of data to the shift registers.

Comment: You can blink them faster than the human eye can see. What are you actually trying to make them do though?

Comment: I am working on a bicycle wheel display project and now trying to figure out the how fast i can blink the LEDs and therefore figure out the resolution (do you have any idea on the resolution?).

Answer (score 1):

**For full transfer via bit-bang:**

`SBI` on the 2313 takes 2 cycles per operation. At two operations per bit plus another to latch, that's 130 cycles.

**For adjacent blink via bit-bang (e.g. 010101 <=> 101010):**

One operation for the set, one for the shift, one for the latch. 6 cycles.

**For full transfer via USI:**

7 cycles to get the byte into the USI via the simplified SPI master example in the datasheet plus the time required to actually send out the bits, all times 4, plus the latch.

38 cycles per byte using the high-speed SPI master example, times 4, plus the latch.

**Conclusion:**

At 1 / 20MHz = 50ns per cycle, *much* faster than your eye can see. Consider using one of the timers with an interrupt instead of banging it out manually.

Comment: Thank you for your detail explanation. By the way, what are SBI, USI and SPI??

Comment: By the way, where do you get the information about 'SBI on the 2313 takes 2 cycles per operation.'? Thanks

Comment: @user29542: From the "Instruction Set Summary" section of the ATtiny2313/V datasheet.

Answer (score 1):

"Persistance of Vision" displays, while someone similar to PWM, are not the same thing. Your resolution depends on the size of the wheel, and the max or average speed/rpm, the speed of your shift registers.

((1/(rpm/60)) / x ) * 1000 = time on per pixel per rotation in milliseconds

(rpm/60) * x = number of times you need to update the display in hertz.

where x is number of pixels you want in a single rotation.

As Ignacio has shown, simply 32 bits of data via bitbang is 130 cycles. Times ns per cycle, thats 130 * 50ns = 6.5 µs (microseconds) per 32 bits of data at its fastest with the best code you can write.

Based on [this chart](http://www.endless-sphere.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=16114) a 20 inch wheel at 15mph is 252 rpm. Say you want 720 pixels (2 per degree), that means its 0.331ms or 331µs per pixel, and 3.024 kHz.

Compare that to standard low speed i2c bus timing of just 100khz, which is 10µs per bit. High speed buses can figure in the mHz (like usb 2.0 full speed is 480mhz).

Note that this doesn't take into account how the father you go from the center of the wheel, the faster it moves, at the same RPM. Angular vs Linear Speed. This means the inside leds will need to be updated faster than the outside leds, because the distance they travel is smaller. The diameter of led 1 on the inside is 10" but led 28 is 19".

Comment: Actually, if you wanted to have the same areal resolution then the LEDs on the outside would have to be updated more often since they move further than the inner ones in the same amount of time.